# Log software usage time on Mac OS 9 (Oct. 1999)

Tags: mac, applescript, bash

I'm needing to log the time a user spends inside of an application in Mac OS 9. I created a simple bash script "launcher" to do this, but then discovered OS 9 doesn't have bash installed. Here is the bash script I wrote for reference.

```
#!/bin/bash

APP="TextEdit"  
LOG_LOCATION=~/Desktop/textedit-usage.log

run_app() {
    USER=`whoami`
    START_TIME=`date`
    echo "START - $APP - $USER - $START_TIME" >> $LOG_LOCATION
    Open -W -a $APP
    END_TIME=`date`
    echo "END - $APP - $USER - $END_TIME" >> $LOG_LOCATION
}

run_app &
```

It creates a simple log file that looks something like this:

```
START - TextEdit - john - Tue Jan  7 15:14:55 EST 2014
END - TextEdit - john - Tue Jan  7 15:15:48 EST 2014
```

Is there a way to port this script to OS 9? I was thinking AppleScript might work, but am having trouble finding documentation for the specific version used in OS 9. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: That script doesn't say how long you are in an app but how long the app is open. I open several apps on login and don't shut them until logout but I am only using them for a small amount of time

Comment: 10.9 mavericks or 9 from October, 1999?

Comment: 9 from October, 1999

Comment: @Mark That's true. If you know of a way to only create a log entry when the application is in focus, I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is install [Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard), on a PowerPC PowerMac and then install OS 9 into the [Classic Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Environment), and have your user run their application there. You can still find new and full [retail versions](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=os+x+10.5+leopard+%28sealed%2C+new%2C+nos%29&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xos+x+10.5+leopard+retail+%28sealed%2C+new%2C+nos%29&_nkw=os+x+10.5+leopard+retail+%28sealed%2C+new%2C+nos%29&_sacat=0) of Leopard with the licensing intact, and [online support](http://www.apple.com/support/leopard/) is still available.

Then, I'd use your bash script (with a possibly needed slight modification to track use of the entire Classic Environment rather than the specific application). ;-)